# PBI: Filter orders if more than one order per trip

Tags: powerbi

G'day,

I have the below sales data:

[image]

I need to filter this list as a visual to show only trips with 2 or more orders on it.

Included Lines:

[image]

Excluded lines:

[image]

Note that "Trip #" 1 has 2 orders, but 3 order lines. This is how my data is formatted and needs to remain that way as there is other data on the lines which I need to show on the report.

Comment: Please can you paste  your tables in markdown format. Do you want a DAX or Power Query solution?

Comment: @DavideBacci DAX is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Measure similar to either of the following:

This version will count the number of rows by Trip:

```
Trip # count w/ 2+Orders = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[Trip #]),
    IF(
      CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('YourTable'),
        ALLEXCEPT('YourTable', 'YourTable'[Trip #])
      ) > 1,
      1
    )
  )
```

This version will count distinct Orders by Trip:

```
Trip # count w/ 2+Orders = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[Trip #]),
    IF(
      CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('YourTable'[Order #]),
        ALLEXCEPT('YourTable', 'YourTable'[Trip #])
      ) > 1,
      1
    )
  )
```

This will give you the count of `Trip #` with 2 or more orders. You can then add this to a visual, or add it as a Visual filter in the Filter pane and set it to `is not blank`.

Comment: This seems to do what I need, thanks! I have had a look at the code and think it is missing something though. Does this filter out by LINE or ORDER #? If I have a trip with two lines but those two lines are on the same ORDER will it be included here? I want to exclude those. I only want to see it if the orders are more than 2 distinct values.

Comment: Updated the answer above with two versions. If you want to count those with more than 2 (and not more than 1) then update `> 1` to `> 2` etc....